# Google collaboratory shows disk half full while there are no files in file explorer

Tags: google-colaboratory

Here is a photo of my Google Collaboratory file explorer

[image: e]

The only folders shown are Colab's default `sample_data` folder and my `Google Drive` which is mounted to Collaboratory and it's not supposed to occupy any volume in the collaboratory disk. But my disk is shown half full and I need it to be completely empty. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Colab occupies about 28 gb, I think they are the images of the os and the different packages it has preinstalled, like tensorflow, pandas, etc. You can see this also when changing runtime (`Runtime Menu -> Change runtime type`). If you set for example GPU hardware acceleration, you will have in this case about 300 usable gb, but even in this case the 28 gb are occupied. You can have a look of what is preinstalled clicking on the circled command.

[image: Colab Root]